# Call someone on the same network using VOIP calls

Tags: networking, home-networking, voip, voice

Is there a VOIP software where I can call a friend on the same local network? I should be able to add friends via their local IP addresses and provided they have the same software installed, be able to call them and speak to them via my headset.

Someone recommended an [H323](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.323) client or [Blink](http://icanblink.com/) but I don't understand how it works.

Heard of any software that make IP to IP calls?

Comment: What is your operating system and that of your friend?

Comment: Windows XP and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a VOIP type application for this, you want a gamer voice-chat application like [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) or Teamspeak.  It's a very similar concept but designed to be used on LANs and for end users to run their own servers without requiring any internet access.

Mumble in particular is [very easy to install on Windows](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/Installing_Mumble).

Answer (score 0):

@Jenko:

In linux we have nice features. I use linux desktop SJPhone (FREE). And then i install Wine, and install windows version of SJPhone (FREE). Then i can call both in same pc via IP to IP or Alias to Alias.

If you want to do more. You can download FREE H323 server for Linux or  Windows. And setup within 5 minutes.

I used that server called GnuGK/OpenH323gk. It allows lot of complex solutions so solve. If you need to do more just Peer to peer. you can use also http://www.silvo.de/Homer/   (FREE)

If it helps, let me know. :)